# How can I mock the creation of directory in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is the method that creates a directory.

```
def create_directory(path)
   system 'mkdir', '-p', path
end
```

I created an `rspec` for this method and used `fakefs` to mock the creation of directory.

```
it 'should create directory given path as parameter' do
     FakeFS do
       create_directory(DIRECTORY_PATH)
     end
     expect(File.exists?(DIRECTORY_PATH)).to be_truthy
end
```

When I execute the `rspec` command, I got this error.

```
    Failures:

      1) common Test for common method use should create file given file as parameter
         Failure/Error: expect(File.exists?(DIRECTORY_PATH)).to be_truthy

           expected: truthy value
                got: false
         # ./spec/unit/lib/common_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 0.01474 seconds (files took 0.10763 seconds to load)
    2 examples, 1 failure

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/unit/lib/common_spec.rb:12 # common Test for common method use should create file given file as parameter
```

How to mock the creation of directory using rspec or fakefs?

Comment: there **is no** question in your question

Comment: hi @AndreyDeineko, I added a question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [ruby tools](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir) for creating directory instead of shelling out.
2. Move your expectation into the fakefs block.

Comment: hi @Sergio, thanks for the advice. It works properly in the rspec.

Comment: yes, it works now. I just followed your recommendations. Thanks for the help @Sergio.

Comment: I accept it but it doesn't reflect publicly because my reputation is below 15.

Comment: @micmicsuarez: hm, interesting. Never heard of this. You're talking about the green checkmark, right?

Comment: sorry @Sergio, I clicked the wrong button. It is now accepted. Thanks :)